# MySQL performance and optimization with multiple queries on a profile page, can they be reduced?

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, social-networking, reduce

I am working on social networking site, which has a profile page for each user.

The profile page contains:

- info about the user, avatar, hobbies & etc
- their videos and photos
- their friends
- their bookmarks
- videos they watched

At the moment i execute 14 different queries each time  profile page is loaded, some of  them listed below:

- check if the viewer is allowed to view the profile page
- get profile info
- get profile videos
- get profile photos
- get friend list
- get bookmark list
- get videos they watched

I would like to know best way to improve the performance and optimize my site, or can i reduce the number of queries i run.

Can MySQL handle this much load?

if it helps i am using innodb engine i needed faster updating speed as well realtionships.

thanks :)

Comment: As far as the *amount*, 14 queries is nothing. Don't worry, keep developing. Optimize later.

Answer (score 0):

If it ever does become a performance issue, here are a couple of easy things that will help:

- Cache the queries on the db server
- Cache the results of the queries in the web app
- Cache the entire profile page, or parts of it which change infrequently.

If you need to get more serious, you can create a new table in the database that stores the results of some of your queries all in one row, and regenerate it periodically. Then have your page select from that (then you have everything you need in one query).

But most importantly: what @Jason said. Chances are if performance does become an issue (because you turn into the next twitter or something), it'll be cheaper to throw hardware at the problem than to rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

As long as they are short-running queries it's okay. Doing anything to optimize speed might give you, at best, some additional milliseconds. If it still bothers, you could do some caching.

Lookup also `memcache`.